# how to concatenate 3 text fields values and pass to hidden text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<label class="textRight label95 select205">Cost Center: </label>
<input type="hidden" name="label_0" value="Cost Center" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />
```

I want to combine the values entered in all these text fields and pass in the hidden field here `<input type="hidden" name="label_0" value="Cost Center" />`. How can this be achieved? Please help.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get each item his value, then [`join`](http://api.jquery.com/map/#entry-examples) them.

Like this:

```js
var inputs = $('[name="value_0"]').on('keyup', combine);

function combine() {
  var val = inputs.map((i, input) => input.value).get().join('');
  $('[name=label_0]').val(val);
  console.log($('[name=label_0]').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="textRight label95 select205">Cost Center: </label>
<input type="hidden" name="label_0" value="Cost Center" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" name="value_1" value="" maxlength="10" placeholder="another input - not calculated" />
```

Comment: Sorry Mosh, I think I did not specify my problem correctly. Actually I have lots of text fields in my form, But I just wanted these 3 text fields values to be combined and sent when submitting the form. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Sure it does. Can you say that only they are `[name=value_0]`? If not, can you give them specific `class` or something so we could identify them?

Comment: Assume that only them have the name `value_0` I was updated my answer.

Comment: I see. Implementing the new code and see how it goes. thanks so much Mosh!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
 var Inputs = ('input[type="text"]');
$(Inputs).each(function () {
               
                   $("input[name='label_0']").val($("input[name='label_0']").val()+' '+$(this).val())
               });
               console.log($("input[name='label_0']").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="textRight label95 select205">Cost Center: </label>
<input type="hidden" name="label_0" value="Cost Center" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="1" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="2" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="3" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Rahul I only need the 3 text inputs to be combined and I have more text fields but I dont wnat thier values to be combined. Makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to use the id attribute for your inputs. I assume that you will use the following ids

```
<label class="textRight label95 select205">Cost Center: </label>
<input type="hidden" id="label_0" name="label_0" value="Cost Center" />

<input type="text" id="value_1" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" id="value_2" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" id="value_3" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />
```

You can do what you asked as follows:

```
$("#label_0").val($("#value_1").val() + $("#value_2").val() + $("#value_3").val());
```

**EDIT**

```js
$("#merge").click(function() {
  $("#label_0").val($("#value_1").val() + $("#value_2").val() + $("#value_3").val());
});

$("#getValue").click(function() {
  alert($("#label_0").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="textRight label95 select205">Cost Center: </label>
<input type="hidden" id="label_0" name="label_0" value="Cost Center" />

<input type="text" id="value_1" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" id="value_2" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<input type="text" id="value_3" name="value_0" class="input64 inputTxtGray" value="" maxlength="10" />

<br />

<button id="merge">Merge Values</button>
<button id="getValue">Get Hidden Value</button>
```

Comment: if have more than three textboxes then what we do??

Comment: If you have a variable number of textboxes then you will have to use a loop.

Comment: pitaridis Thanks! But If I need to get the values added and passed with a submit button. How will that be achieved.

Comment: If you convert the merge button to a submit button and include the entire code inside a form tag, the browser will execute the javascript to set the merged value to the hidden field and after that the submition will send the data including the merged value to the server.

Comment: Thanks! But The submit button is not a button but a link, will the click function work for that as well?

Comment: If you want to submit a from from a link you can use the onclick event. `<a href="#" onclick="$('#myform').submit();">Submit</a>`